# Troubles while running neo4j & rails in HA (part 2)

Tags: neo4j

I have configured an HA cluster with 3 nodes.
The first is a Rails server, the second a Rail console, and the last a Neo4j server

I started the Rails s and the Rails c, then I started the other instance, with the error
below.

Here is the config for the three machines:

Rails server and console:

---

module Neo4j

```
  module Rails
    module HaConsole
      class Railtie < Object::Rails::Railtie
        console do
          Neo4j.config.use do |conf|
            server_id = 2
            conf['ha.server_id'] = server_id
            conf['ha.server'] = "localhost:600#{server_id}"
            conf['ha.cluster_server'] = "localhost:500#{server_id}"
            conf['storage_path'] = File.expand_path("db/ha_neo_#{server_id}", Object::Rails.root)
            puts "Re-Config HA cluster, ha.server_id: #{conf['ha.server_id']}, db: #{conf['storage_path']}"
          end
        end

        config.before_configuration do
          server_id = 1
          config.neo4j['enable_ha'] = true
          config.neo4j['ha.server_id'] = server_id
          config.neo4j['ha.server'] = "localhost:600#{server_id}"
          config.neo4j['ha.pull_interval'] = '500ms'
          config.neo4j['ha.discovery.enabled'] = false
          config.neo4j['ha.initial_hosts'] = [1,2,3].map{|id| "localhost:500#{id}"}.join(',')
          config.neo4j['ha.cluster_server'] = "localhost:500#{server_id}"
          config.neo4j.storage_path = File.expand_path("db/ha_neo_#{server_id}", Object::Rails.root)
          puts "Config HA cluster, ha.server_id: #{config.neo4j['ha.server_id']}, db: #{config.neo4j.storage_path}"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

---

the latter is:

```
online_backup_enabled=true
online_backup_server=localhost:6362
ha.server_id=3
ha.initial_hosts=localhost:5001,localhost:5002,localhost:5003
ha.server=localhost:6003
ha.cluster_server=localhost:5003
ha.pull_interval=1
```

---

There is also a timeout from the server (id=3), and, when the port 7474 became available, ther is no sync with the other 2 cluster elements. Moreover, a red banner sometimes appera on top of the 7474 console, sayng 'Lost connection with Neo4j. Please check the plug".

Has anyone an idea?

Paolo

---

2013-11-21 23:48:57.473+0000 INFO  [Cluster] Attempting to join cluster of [127.0.0.1:5001, 127.0.0.1:5002, 127.0.0.1:5003]
2013-11-21 23:49:02.568+0000 INFO  [Cluster] Joined cluster:Name:neo4j.ha Nodes:{1=cluster://127.0.0.1:5001, 3=cluster://127.0.0.1:5003} Roles:{coordinator=1}
2013-11-21 23:49:02.582+0000 INFO  [Cluster] Instance 3 (this server) joined the cluster
2013-11-21 23:49:06.845+0000 INFO  [Cluster] Instance 1 was elected as coordinator
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2598)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1318)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at org.neo4j.cluster.member.paxos.PaxosClusterMemberEvents$HighAvailabilitySnapshotProvider.setState(PaxosClusterMemberEvents.java:179)
    at org.neo4j.cluster.protocol.snapshot.SnapshotMessage$SnapshotState.setState(SnapshotMessage.java:91)
    at org.neo4j.cluster.protocol.snapshot.SnapshotState$2.handle(SnapshotState.java:105)
    at org.neo4j.cluster.protocol.snapshot.SnapshotState$2.handle(SnapshotState.java:89)
    at org.neo4j.cluster.statemachine.StateMachine.handle(StateMachine.java:88)
    at org.neo4j.cluster.StateMachines$1.run(StateMachines.java:135)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Comment: Which Neo4j version is this?

Comment: And shouldn't the rails console be configured similarly to the other two?

Comment: Looks like its related to this github issue: https://github.com/andreasronge/neo4j/issues/287#issuecomment-29141291